# How to install MultiNEAT

Tags: python, boost, anaconda, conda

I am installing MultiNEAT at conda.

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5
source activate py35
conda install multineat -c conda-forge
```

The installation ended normally, but when importing, the following error appears

```
python
Python 3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Aug 26 2018, 21:41:56) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MultiNEAT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/bc/anaconda3/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/sitepackages/MultiNEAT/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ._MultiNEAT import *
ImportError: libboost_system.so.1.67.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Please tell me how to resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [the shared object packaged for linux](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/multineat/files) is linked to a specific version of libboost (1.67.0), even though the conda dependency only specifies >=1.66.  Installing that version from conda-forge seems to be sufficient:

```
conda install -n py35 -c conda-forge boost=1.67.0 boost-cpp=1.67.0
```

You may want to [pin these versions](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#preventing-packages-from-updating-pinning) so future updates don't mess it up.  Also, consider [dropping an issue on the GitHub](https://github.com/peter-ch/MultiNEAT/issues).

Comment: That is correct.
The version of boost installed with conda install multineat was 1.68.0. However, the required boost version was 1.67.0.